# Text hidden behind image

Tags: image, navigation, z-index

I have a problem where my logo image is on top of my navigation links. I have tried different z-index settings.

If I set my .logo `z-index:` to -1 it goes behind the header image, while the navigation links stay above the header image. If I set the .logo `z-index` to 1 and nav0 to 2 or (500 for that matter), I still have the same problem with the logo image being on top of the navigation links.

```
.headerFrame {
  height : 153px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  background-image:url(headerBack.png);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.logo {
  padding : 5px;.headerFrame {
  height: 153px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  background-image:url(headerBack.png);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 805px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20 20 20 20;
  z-index: 1;
}
.logo a img{
  border: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  text-align: center;
}
.accountNav {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 380px;
  padding-top:6px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu0 {
  list-style: none;
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.menu0 ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.menu0 li {
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu0 li a, .menu0 li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0a0a0a;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 8px;
}
.menu0 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```